# Why is my external SSD very fast in the Benchmark, but incredible slow copying to or from other disks?

Tags: ssd, performance, external-hard-drive, windows-10-preview, usb-3.1-type-c

So I formatted my 1TB-SSD (half half in NTFS and exFAT partitions) and put it into a USB-3.1 external case. Both Partitions have fast speeds in CrystalDiskmark Test. (523 M/s read, 428 m/s write)
However, when i start copying files, lets say, to my internal SSD in my laptop, my current speed is around 250 kb/s (!!) Yes, you read right. Thats a slow speed, even compared to an internet transfer.

Any idea whats going on here? As said, by themselves, the from-and-to copying disks are fast!

How can I go about this?

My laptop is an High End i7, btw.

Comment: How many files? How big?

Comment: all mixed, some very tiny files, some quite large (1 Gig or more)

Comment: Most SSD benchmarks test really small files.  I am not sure the relevance your processor has on USB transfer speeds.

Comment: This is probably explained by differences between large sequential reads/writes and small random reads/writes. Large/sequential speed is great for coping large files, and small/random speed is great for lots of small files and using it as a live (especially boot) filesystem. You really need to see the speeds for both kinds of tests in order to know how your device will do in different situations.